# Install and use new font in iPhone Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

I need to install a new font and use it iPhone.I did the following steps:

1. Install a Font  in Fonts Folder.
2. Add Font in iPhone project file. test.otf.
3. Added font name "Fonts provided by application" in Plist file.

   I check this font TextEdit. It is working fine, it is not affect in Interface Builder.

   If i double click the Label to edit text, font is assigned and displaying with font but it is not displaying in normal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not displayed in interface builder. You need to assign that font by code. Something like below.

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Font Name" size:20];
```

Hope this help.